# update date field in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to update my date_process field using php.  The mysql field is a date type field and my code is:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$data =json_decode($_POST['data'], true); 

foreach($data as $value){ 
// update inventory table
$conn->query("update inventory set cost = {$data[$n]['cost']}, 
csmt = {$data[$n]['csmt']}, 
hold = {$data[$n]['hold']},
date_process = $today 
where sku = {$data[$n]['sku']}");
```

All of the other fields are updating properly, just the date_process is returning 000-00-00.  I have looked at other posts, and from what I can tell I am formatting this correctly( or at least I think I am).  Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Take user-supplied POST data, put directly into SQL query. **WHAT COULD POSSIBLY GO WRONG**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding quotes around the date:

```
$conn->query("update inventory set cost = {$data[$n]['cost']}, 
              csmt = {$data[$n]['csmt']}, 
              hold = {$data[$n]['hold']},
              date_process = '$today'
              where sku = {$data[$n]['sku']}");
```

Comment: thanks, that did it.  I knew it must be something simple that I was overlooking.

Comment: You haven't even tried to escape your SQL, and you didn't even mention this might be an issue. This indifferent attitude, this utterly reckless approach to handling arbitrary user-provided data is why PHP applications are constantly being hacked. People use Stack Overflow answers like this as if they were best practices. Do it the right way, please.

Comment: @tadman: Thanks for the input. I think I shouldn't answer PHP questions anymore since my knowledge isn't that wide in that area.

Comment: Writing properly escaped SQL is not just an academic concern, but one that may affect your career and company. If your solution has risks or limitations, always try and communicate that. Obviously this code is given as-is, but here we have, sadly,  yet another example of how not to do PHP. I don't mean to bust on you specifically, this practice is rampant in the PHP section of Stack Overflow. I'm just trying to push back.

Answer (score 0):

What is in `$today`? It's probably in a format that MySQL doesn't really get.

Try something like:

```
update inventory set date_process = date_format(curdate(), "%Y-%m-%d");
```